# Method regex.scanner() cannot be found in the Python 3.5.1 documentation, but the Interpreter works well

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am learning Python with *Python Cookbook, 3rd*. On page 67, here is a sample code like this

```
import re
NAME = r'(?P<NAME>[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)'
NUM = r'(?P<NUM>\d+)'
PLUS = r'(?P<PLUS>\+)'
TIMES = r'(?P<TIMES>\*)'
EQ = r'(?P<EQ>=)'
WS = r'(?P<WS>\s+)'    
master_pat = re.compile('|'.join([NAME, NUM, PLUS, TIMES, EQ, WS]))
scanner = master_pat.scanner('foo = 42')
scanner.match()
 ......
```

I was trying to find the signature of method regex.scanner() in Python Standard Documentation, but I failed.There is nothing about regex.scanner().On the other hand, the sample code runs quick well with the Interpreter.Does anyone know what's the situation?Or it's just a common case of lacking signature details in CPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [hidden gem](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2015/11/18/pythons-hidden-re-gems/) :-)

> This is where things get interesting. For the last 15 years or so,
>   there has been a completely undocumented feature in the regular
>   expression engine: the scanner. The scanner is a property of the
>   underlying SRE pattern object where the engine keeps matching after it
>   found a match for the next one. There even exists an re.Scanner class
>   (also undocumented) which is built on top of the SRE pattern scanner
>   which gives this a slightly higher level interface.
>
> The scanner as it exists in the re module is not very useful
>   unfortunately for making the 'not matching' part faster, but looking
>   at its sourcecode reveals how it's implemented: on top of the SRE
>   primitives.

Comment: Thank u very much for your answer. I've got the point of the problem.I check Python 3.5.1 Documentation again and find a statement in What’s New In Python 3.4, saying "The unused and undocumented internal Scanner class has been removed from the pydoc module".Moreover, there is a method regex.finditer() that can be used to replace regex.scanner().I'd like to use regex.finditer() in my future work since it's quite understandable and documented.